# How can I make the server id an arg discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to python and discord.py so sorry for any confusion. So I'm trying to make a modmail system for my bot however from my understanding there doesn't seem to be a way to get the server id from a dm or like there is, but if the bot is in multiple servers how do I figure out what server to send the message to? My idea was to check the message sent and see if the user sent the id of the server however I don't think I did it very well.

Here's what I currently did and it seems to work fine however just from the looks I know it can't be right.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self,message):

        if not message.author.bot:
            if isinstance(message.channel,DMChannel):

                message_list = message.content.split()
                server_id_sent = message_list[0]

                for guild in self.client.guilds:
                    if str(guild.id) == server_id_sent:
                        message_list.remove(server_id_sent) #I thought by doing this I could remove the id from the message
                        guild = self.client.get_guild(int(server_id_sent))
                        print(guild)
                        modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="modmail")
                        modmail_channel_id = modmail_channel.id
                        channel = self.client.get_channel(modmail_channel_id)

                        await channel.send("TEST")
                    else:
                        await message.channel.send("Please provide the ID of the server")
```

By the way, first time using stackoverflow so hopefully I followed the format correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. We're going to set a command for when a user wants to send something to the specified server.
2. Getting the server name/ID won't actually be useful, as the bot won't know where to send that message. Instead, we will need a channel ID. To make this more user friendly, we're going to set a certain server name with it's channel id (let's just say it could be a log or ticket channel for the bot for these kind of messages)
   I set mine like this:
   `Server: myServer`
   `Server's channel ID: 1234567`
3. Once we got the server name, we will send a message to the corresponding channel ID and send a message to the user that the request has been successfully recieved and made.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("?request"):
       try:
          server_name = message.content.split(' ')[1] #this gets the server name the user specified and saves it in a variable
       except:
          await message.channel.send("Invalid Usage! Syntax: ?request <serverID>")
          return
      
      if server_name == "myServer":
         channel_id = 1234567
      else:
         await message.channel.send(f"The server `{server_name}` is not a valid server.")
         return

      get_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
      await get_channel.send("Hello!")

      #finally we're going to notify the user that his request has been successfully recieved
      await message.channel.send(f"Message successfully sent to `{server_name}`!")
```

I am aware that

```
if server_name == "myServer":
   channel_id = 1234567
```

is not really an elegant solution. If you want to store multiple servers with their respective logs channels ID's you could just store them in a dict or in a json file. Then access them in this way.
Json file example:

```
{
  "myServer": "1234567",
  "mySecondServer": 0987675
}
```

```
import json

json_file = open('servers.json').read()
servers = json.loads(json_file)

try:
   get_channel_from_server = servers[server_name]
except:
   await message.channel.send(f"The server `{server_name}` is not a valid server.")
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well only question is to get the message do I just do another try exception and put ```message.content.split(' ')[2]```?

Comment: Yes. but you should have all of your arguments in the same try/except block, and if the user does not specify one you just send something like `Invalid Usage! Syntax: ?request <serverID> <message>` @ObviousQuantity

Comment: Hmm so this seems to only get the first word. if I did ?request (id) this is a test it's only gonna send the word "this" how can I send the rest of the message? lol

Comment: You need to split the line and then parse the content after it.
`text = message.content.split(server_name) -> user_request = text[1]`